# How to create virtual folder like Dropbox or OneDrive in navigation pane (Windows) or Finder (Mac OS) programatically?

Tags: shell-namespace-extension

We have cloud-based web application in which users upload their documents and manage it folder wise.

We would like to develop desktop application like Dropbox and OneDrive in which users can manage and sync their files and folder from local machine to cloud vice-e-versa.

Which technologies should use to develop this type of desktop application?

1. Python
2. Node.js
3. Electron.js
4. Shell Namespace Extension

Image 1

[image: image 1]

Image 2

[image: image 2]

Thanks & Regards
Rachit V. Sakhidas

Comment: Bro, I want to do the same, did you manage to do that?

Comment: Any update on this? I am trying to do the same thing.